# PHP preg_match vs ctype_

Tags: php

I have read multiple times, that using the `ctype_xyz` functions is faster and better then using regular expressions. But I did some tests and regular expressions are way faster.

See example below :

> PHP Version: 7.2
>
> OS: Windows

```
<?php

$foo = '112312312312323';

$start_time = microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    $foo = $foo.'1';
    preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $foo);
    // ctype_alnum($foo); 
}

$end_time = microtime(true);

echo 'Result: ' . ($end_time - $start_time);
```

With `preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $foo);` the output is `Result: 0.094325065612793`

With `ctype_alnum($foo);` the output is : `Result: 1.8465659618378`

Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: I tried different versions and ctype is about twice as fast http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e3b9ddc370fdb0f00ff40447eadc24def0dd1abe

Comment: I ran your script on my vm, php 7.2 - regular expression `0.06`, ctype_alnum `0.02` so in my case - `ctype_alnum` is 3x faster.

Comment: Looks like it is opposite on HHVM which I know nothing about https://3v4l.org/fjSaZ#vhhvm-3220. Scroll down.

Comment: So I should have added, that I am running this on Windows. So maybe this is the difference? On Unix/Linux ctype is faster and on Windows preg_match. Weird...

Comment: Well in all honesty, would you ever run PHP in production on Windows?

Comment: Of course I would not, but this is not the question here ;)
I have to develop under windows unfortunately

Comment: Oracle Virtualbox + Vagrant + Homestead, a simple `vagrant up` and you can develop under windows using all the nice stuff that Linux gives us. I've no clue if you can do that, or if you're aware of it, just dropping this off in case you might find it useful.

Comment: I got WSL or VMware Workstation and also Linux PC  - thank you anyways.
But again: my question is just WHY it behaves like that on Windows.